# Random Variables Probability

Tags: statistics, random-variables

On a multiple-choice exam with 3 possible answers for each of the 5 questions, what is the probability that a student will get 4 or more correct answers just by guessing?

So to begin this problem I began with (5-choose-4)/(3^5) + (5-choose-5)/(3^5) but that answer was incorrect.

I'm not sure how to actually go about this problem so any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I began with (5-choose-4)/(3^5) + (5-choose-5)/(3^5)

It's a good *start*.  You are multiplying the probability of getting $k$ answers correct, in a certain order, by the number of permutations of that arrangement.  However, you need to include the probability of getting $5-k$ answers incorrect.

$${5\choose 4}\cdot \frac{1^4}{3^4} \cdot\frac{ 2^1}{3^1}+ {5\choose 5}\cdot \frac{1^5}{3^5}\cdot\frac{2^0}{3^0} = \frac{11}{243}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let A be an event that the student gets exactly 4 answers correct and B be the event
that the student gets all of the 5 answers correct. Then the desired probability is

$ P(A) + P(B) = 5(1/3)^4(2/3) + (1/3)^5 $

Now you can simplify it to end up with the solution.